# Object lifetime

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
class Beta{}
class Alpha {
   static Beta b1;
   Beta b2;
}

void main (..){
 Beta b1 = new Beta();
 Beta b2 = new Beta();
 Alpha a1 = new Alpha();
 Alpha a2 = new Alpha();
 a1.b1=b1;
 a1.b2=b1;
 a2.b2=b2;
 a1=null; b1=null; b2 = null;
 // do stuff
}
```

This is a sample Java certificate question that I don't seem to understand. The question asks how many objects eligible for GC at line //do stuff, the answer is 1 object, while I am thinking 4. Can some one explain?
So, the first Beta object referenced by b1 and a1 should be eligible for GC since b1 = null and a1 = null. Shouldn't the Alpha object referenced by a1 also be eligible for GC since a1 = null and nothing else references it? Or would it have been eligible had the instance Beta b1 variable not been static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one object is eligible for GC.  Let 1A, 2A, 1B, 2B represent the first and second object instances (not references) of A and B, respectively.  I've annotated your code with comments after each step to reflect the current state of references to the four objects.

```
class Beta{}
class Alpha {
   static Beta b1;
   Beta b2;
}

void main (..){
 Beta b1 = new Beta();
 Beta b2 = new Beta();
 Alpha a1 = new Alpha();
 Alpha a2 = new Alpha();
 //1A <- pointed to by a1
 //2A <- pointed to by a2
 //1B <- pointed to by b1
 //2B <- pointed to by b2 

 a1.b1=b1;
 //1A <- pointed to by a1
 //2A <- pointed to by a2
 //1B <- pointed to by b1, Alpha.b1
 //2B <- pointed to by b2 

 a1.b2=b1;
 //1A <- pointed to by a1
 //2A <- pointed to by a2
 //1B <- pointed to by b1, Alpha.b1, a1.b2
 //2B <- pointed to by b2 

 a2.b2=b2;
 //1A <- pointed to by a1
 //2A <- pointed to by a2
 //1B <- pointed to by b1, Alpha.b1
 //2B <- pointed to by b2, a2.b2 

 a1=null; b1=null; b2 = null;
 //1A <- Eligible for GC
 //2A <- pointed to by a2
 //1B <- pointed to by Alpha.b1
 //2B <- pointed to by a2.b2 

// do stuff
}
```

Comment: So, a1 is eligible for GC even though its static member still pointing to another object? static has no bearing on the object lifetime since its Class related? Also, is a1 eligible for GC even though a1.b2 is pointing to another object Beta (1B), Would it make a difference if 1B is alive or not?

Comment: 1A has no static member. Static means it belongs to the class, not to any instance.  When evaluating 1A, the GC does not care what objects 1A has references to; it only cares what whether there are any references to 1A. Because nothing refers to 1A at the end of this example, the GC knows it can safely be deleted.  Basically, if nothing points to 1A, 1A can be deleted. If 1A has references to other objects, these references will help to keep the other objects alive (until 1A is deemed eligible for GC) but have no effect on keeping 1A alive.

Answer (score 2):

Only a1 is eligible for GC.

b1 is refered by the static member of Alpha (due to `a1.b1 = b1;`).
b2 is refered by the non-static member of a2 (due to `a2.b2 = b2;`).
a2 refernce is not set to null.

Comment: I am still a bit confused, if a1 is eligible, but a1 has reference to static and non static members. Doesn't the non-static member create an object on the heap by itself, so so would actually make 2 objects not just one?

Comment: @user1529412 The program instantiated 4 objects, two of type Alpha and two of type Beta. `a1` refers to a non-static member `b1`, but it also refers to `b1` via the static member of Alpha. The static reference remains even after you set the `a1` reference to null and `a1` is garbage collected. Setting the member to refer to an existing object doesn't create a new object. Only the 4 `new` constructor calls create objects.